# xcb: wait/poll for reply OR event

Tags: c, x11, xcb

XCB provides functions `xcb_{wait,poll}_for_{reply,event}`, but not `xcb_{wait,poll}_for_reply_or_event`, which would be useful in the following scenario:

1. Send a batch of requests.
2. Wait for replies. While waiting, handle incoming events.
3. When the replies finally come in, handle the replies.

To implement steps 2 and 3, we could `poll` the underlying socket, as follows:

1. Check for queued replies with `xcb_poll_for_reply`.
2. Check for queued events with `xcb_poll_for_event`.
3. `poll` the underlying socket.
4. When `poll` indicates a read is possible, call `xcb_poll_for_reply` and/or `xcb_poll_for_event` and process the new data.

However, this seems to have a race condition. If a reply (but not an event) arrives between steps 1 and 2, it will get queued in XCB's internal data structures in step 2. Then we will end up blocking in `poll` even though there is data available to process. (Of course, a similar issue occurs if steps 1 and 2 are swapped.)

**So, is there any efficient way to wait/poll for replies *or* events without this deficiency?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by `poll`ing the underlying socket as described in the question, but with `xcb_poll_for_event` in step 2 replaced by `xcb_poll_for_queued_event`. (This might still be broken in multithreaded scenarios.)

Alternatively, we can avoid needing to `poll` the socket by sending an unchecked dummy request that is guaranteed to fail, as follows:

1. Send a batch of requests.
2. Send an unchecked dummy request that will fail (e.g., MapWindow with an invalid window argument).
3. Repeatedly call `xcb_wait_for_event` and handle incoming events while waiting for replies.
4. Eventually, `xcb_wait_for_event` will return an error. If the sequence number in the error matches the sequence number of the dummy request, then ignore the error and continue to the next step; all replies must have arrived. Otherwise, the error is for a genuine request and should be handled appropriately.
5. Read in all replies with `xcb_poll_for_reply` or the appropriate generated reply functions.

The first approach is more efficient, but the second approach might lead to simpler code.